# Find $x$ given $y$ for monotonic increasing function

Tags: functions, optimization

Given $f(x)$ is a monotone increasing function, and value $y$, describe an algorithm to identify $x$ such that $f(x) = y$, where $x$ is a positive integer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method ?

Comment: you are right. I confused monotone increasing with monotone non-decreasing

Comment: If $x>y\Rightarrow f(x)>f(y)$ then $f$ is said to be 'strictly increasing', if $x>y\Rightarrow f(x)\ge f(y)$ then $f$ is said to be  monotonically increasing (also increasing or non-decreasing) [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). The answer to 'wouldn't stuck' -- I think no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists many but the classical bisection search does not assume differentiability.

Define 
$$
g(x) = f(x) - y
$$
which is again monotone increasing. Now suppose you can find $a, b$ such that $g(a) < 0$ and $g(b) > 0$. Just choose a really small (or really negative) and $b$ really large. Then compute 
$$
c = \frac{b + a}{2}
$$
if $g(c) > 0$ we know that the function $g$ must have crossed the x-axis at some point in $[a, c]$. Conversely if $g(c) < 0$ we know that the function $g$ must cross the x-axis at some point $[c, b]$.

Now depending on where you located the function to cross the x-axis you reassign $a, b = a ,c $ (if $g(c) > 0$) or $a, b = c, b$ (if $g(x) < 0$). Then you repeat the entire process.

By iteratively doing this you are at each step halving the size of the interval where the function $g$ crosses the x-axis and thus where the function $f(x) = y$. At some point the interval will be so small that you can conclude to have approximately identified the value $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

[More info on bisection search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)